# FTP/SFTP/FTPS proxying

Tags: linux, proxy, ftp, sftp, ftps

Greetings, I have a series of external FTP sites that I need to allow users behind my firewalls to access for day-to-day work. We don't allow direct access out to the Internet, we proxy everything and as such, have been forced to set up a machine on the perimeter of our network and forced our users to remote desktop into the machine to interact with these various client sites.

The issue is that for the life of me I can't seem to find anything that will gracefully handle all 3 types of FTP connectivity. FTP proxying is possible, but I haven't seen anything that seems to elegantly handle FTPS and SFTP as well as a single solution (preferrably open souce). I can proxy SFTP through netcat easily enough but FTPS is a trickier beast and I'm pretty much spent as far as searching on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at tlswrap?

I'd seriously consider using a SOCKS proxy for everything, though.

Comment: I implemented Dante (http://www.inet.no/dante/) and it's handling FTP and FTPS without a problem, but SFTP proxying isn't working. Not sure why, since I figured SSH would be far easier to deal with than FTP/S

Comment: Never mind, I'm just a moron (the usual culprit). It works wonderfully for everything. Thanks for the answer!